# How to make a ssl forwarding script that runs once per page load

Tags: javascript, html, forward

I have been having some trouble using a javascript script that automatically makes you get forwarded to use ssl. example,

> http://www.example.com/link becomes https://www.example.com/link

But my issue is that is continuously loads the script, but I want it to stop when it is already loaded. It reloads continuously, making it very annoying and hard to click the links on the page.

Here is my current script

> window.location = "https://" + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine whether a page is secure via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414809/how-do-i-determine-whether-a-page-is-secure-via-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
if(window.location.protocol == 'http:') {
    window.location = "https://" + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
}
```

...or even better:

```
if(window.location.protocol == 'http:') {
    window.location.replace(window.location.toString().replace(/^http:/, 'https:'));
}
```

Second variant is better because:

- URL may be complex and will be handled properly
- Because of using `window.location.replace()` instead of directly assigning a string to `window.location`, previous URL will be removed from history and when user clicks 'back' button, he will jump to original page, not to the one with "http:" protocol: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

But it's better to implement this on server side.

Comment: Thanks! The second seems to load the page a lot faster.